Print more than one column of `lsof' output while sorting and counting uniq values using one of those columns
I want to print only chosen columns of lsof output 
$1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10 
and use uniq -c on the PID column while printing all of the initial columns of output.
I am on macOS. I am using awk, sort, uniq -c
I store the IP address of my machine in a variable: $ETH_IP
ETH_IP="192.168.10.191" && echo $ETH_IP
192.168.10.191

This is my current command with some formatting and its result:
(lsof -alP -Ts -i @"$ETH_IP" -s TCP:ESTABLISHED,LISTEN,CLOSE_WAIT +c0 |sed 's|\\x20|_|g' |awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10}' |column -t)                                     
COMMAND                      PID    USER  TYPE  NODE
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
GitHub_Desktop_Helper        1196   501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
GitHub_Desktop_Helper        1196   501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)

I want to use something like | sort | uniq -c | sort -n. 
Using the value from column 2 (PID) for uniq.
Uing awk and keep the formatting as above with multiple columns.
So there are is only one listing for each process with the quantity of original lines listed in front of the row.
A mockup of what I am looking for.
COMMAND                         PID    USER  TYPE  NODE  
18 Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)
 2 GitHub_Desktop_Helper        1196   501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)
 2 Code_Helper                  1493   501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)
14 com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)
 3 Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)
 2 DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP                (ESTABLISHED)    

The issue I am facing is that the HEADER line is also being counted by uniq -c
(lsof -alP -Ts -i @"$ETH_IP" -s TCP:ESTABLISHED,LISTEN,CLOSE_WAIT +c0 |sed 's|\\x20|_|g' |awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10}' |column -t) | sort -k 2,2 | uniq -c | sort  -n -k 3,3
   1 COMMAND                      PID    USER  TYPE  NODE
   3 accountsd                    667    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
  16 Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
   2 GitHub_Desktop_Helper        1196   501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
  12 com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
   2 Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
   2 DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)

The idea comes from this command and its output.
lsof -alP -Ts -i @"$ETH_IP"  -s TCP:ESTABLISHED,LISTEN,CLOSE_WAIT  +c0 | awk 'NR>2{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
   1 CloudTelemetryService
   1 cloudd
   2 Dropbox
   2 DropboxFileProvider
   2 GitHub\x20Desktop\x20Helper
  14 com.apple.WebKit.Networking
  17 Mail



This sort of gives me the result I want but is ungainly. If there is a better/faster solution I am interested in it.
ETH_IP="192.168.10.191" && echo $ETH_IP
192.168.10.191

lsof -alP -Ts -i @"$ETH_IP" -s TCP:ESTABLISHED,LISTEN,CLOSE_WAIT +c0 |sed 's|\\x20|_|g' |awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10}' \
  | awk 'NR<2{print "#", $0; next}{print $0 |"sort -n -k 2 |uniq -c"}'|column -t


#   COMMAND                      PID    USER  TYPE  NODE
16  Mail                         668    501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
2   GitHub_Desktop_Helper        1196   501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
2   Code_Helper                  1493   501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
8   com.apple.WebKit.Networking  12635  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
2   Dropbox                      74706  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)
2   DropboxFileProvider          74707  501   IPv4  TCP   (ESTABLISHED)

